# Builder pattern build() method output

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, builder

After reading the Design Patterns book and looking at Builder pattern examples online, I have noticed that there are two different ways of returning the object in the final "build()" method. I was wondering what is the difference between:

Simply returning the `maze` we have been building

```
public class MazeBuilderImpl implements MazeBuilder {

private Maze maze;

@Override
public MazeBuilder builder() {
    maze = new Maze();
    return this;
}

// adding rooms, doors etc.

@Override
public Maze build() {
    return maze;
}
}
```

Passing the `maze` as a parameter in a constructor and returning that

```
public class MazeBuilderImpl implements MazeBuilder {

private Maze maze;

@Override
public MazeBuilder builder() {
    maze = new Maze();
    return this;
}

// adding rooms, doors etc.

@Override
public Maze build() {
    return new Maze(maze);
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First one seems worse. The original builder can subsequently be used to modify the state of the built object, since it still holds a reference to it.

```
MazeBuilder builder = new MazeBuilderImpl();
Maze maze = builder.rooms(1).build();
builder.rooms(2); // modifies the state of maze ...
```

The copy in the second one prevents that from happening, and allows the builder to be reused.

Both are bad though, since Maze is implied to be mutable. Builders are best for building immutable objects. It requires re-declaring the fields of Maze as fields of MazeBuilder, i.e. if Maze has a `String id` field, so will MazeBuilder. [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) can help with reducing that boilerplate.

Comment: cheers Michael, that makes perfect sense! Been using Lombok's @Builder very often but tried to actually recreate the Builder to understand how it works under the covers.

Comment: @Kris If you're using IntelliJ, somewhere under Code > Refactor, there is an option to "delombok" Lombok-annotated code, which will convert your source to match  exactly what it's generating. Can be useful to see what's going on. Not sure about other IDEs.

Comment: @Kris, note there are several different "Builder" pattern implementations. Lombok generates something like the Builder pattern from Josh Bloch's Effective Java. The GoF Builder pattern is more complex (and IMO less useful). Mark Seemann has blogged about some of the different [Builders](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2020/02/10/builder-isomorphisms/).

Comment: @jaco0646 I always skipped Builder in GoF's book before, because I never felt like I needed to read it, but after reading your comment I did, and I'd go one further than "complex": it's actively bad, and not something a beginner should be trying to emulate.

Comment: thanks guys, I think the tip for de-lomboking the code worked well and I am happy with my understanding of Builder from that.

Answer (score 1):

If you return same object as in builder as follow:

```
@Override
public Maze build() {
    return maze;
}
```

then you will be referencing same object present in builder. And it can be still muted (changed). So your object could be still changes from somewhere. It still one object that you can affect directly or throuht builder.

If you return different object, you dont have to worry about builder affecting it after calling `build()`.

But if your object can be immutable, then its common to have copy of objects fields in builder and construct object in `build()` method.

```
public class MazeBuilderImpl implements MazeBuilder {

    private Room roomA;
    private Room roomB;
    private Door doorA;
    private Door doorB;
    ....


    // adding rooms, doors etc.

    @Override
    public Maze build() {
        return new Maze(roomA, roomB, doorA, doorB, ...);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for writing out the example kubacech! Will give upvote but tick Michael's answer because he was first.